# what word class are the following words?

Tags: meaning

Ok, so I would like to know what word class numbers are and also time? for example twelve or seven o'clock?

Comment: What do you think they are? Why is it important to know the answer? Why don't you think they are *nouns*?

Comment: How snide and unhelpful. Certainly numbers can be other than nouns.  Merriam-Webster online shows "three" as a noun, pronoun, and adjective.         http://i.word.com/idictionary/three   And what do you suppose it is in "I ate three more pieces of pie"?

Comment: @BrianHitchcock Exactly the question that needed to be asked. The OP question is far shy from being able to be answered authoritatively. But to ask a good question on ELU, it would help to know what problem the question solves, and, hopefully, what specific research might have been done prior to asking here. If the answer *depends* on the question, there is little here to go on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, in linguistics numbers are called "numerals".

Edit: They definitely are. Check out this [Wikipedia article about numerals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeral_%28linguistics%29). I believe that's what you were looking for?

Regarding time: That's also a numeral. Numbers are always numerals, and seven o'clock is nothing but a numeral + a shorter version of "of the clock".